# ndpointer in ctypes structure field

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I cannot figure out how to use [numpy.ndpointer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html) as a field in a python ctypes structure.  Here is some basic code, showing how I can do this without using ndpointer, but I would like to know if it's possible to use ndpointer as well if it's possible!

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class MyStruct_Working(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ('values', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))]
    
    
    def __init__(self, a, values):
        self.a = a
        self.values = values.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

class MyStruct_NotWorking(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ('values', np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=float, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'))]
    
    
    def __init__(self, a, values):
        self.a = a
        self.values = values
```

Using the above code this works fine

```py
m0 = MyStruct_Working(1, np.array([1,2,3]))
```

But when I call this, I get the following error message

```py
m1 = MyStruct_NotWorking(1, np.array([1,2,3]))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8435d2743b55> in <module>
----> 1 m1 = MyStruct_NotWorking(1, np.array([1,2,3]))

<ipython-input-17-beb0591858e6> in __init__(self, a, values)
     17     def __init__(self, a, values):
     18         self.a = a
---> 19         self.values = values

TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

According to [[NumPy]: numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=None, ndim=None, shape=None, flags=None)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer) (**emphasis** is mine):

> An ndpointer instance is used to **describe an ndarray in restypes and argtypes specifications**.

*argtypes* and *restype* only have meaning in the context of a function (call), and that is when *ndpointer* should be used (exemplified in the *URL*).

As a workaround, you can have an *ndpointer* structure member, but you have to initialize it in the same manner as the *ctypes.POINTER* one (in *MyStruct_Working*). However, bear in mind that this will come with some limitations (you won't have indexing) afterwards. 
My suggestion is to stick with *ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)*.